# how to edit a secure cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies

i've seen some websites that you cannot get or edit theirs cookie with javascript (just can be seen in browser tool). What kind of cookie are they? How to edit them via javascript?

Comment: *cannot get or edit theirs cookie with javascript* ... *How to edit them via javascript?* Notice something here? If you cannot do it then you cannot do it! They are http-only cookies: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly

Comment: you sound like you are up to no good.

Answer (score 3):

They are using HTTPOnly cookies: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html. They can be neither retrieved nor modified from JavaScript. In other words, the answer to your question "How to edit them via javascript?" is: you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old, but this answer might be helpful to some one.

You can modify these kind of cookies in your browser by installing a plugin like `Cookie Editor` https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/cookie-editor/, and turn off httponly for that cookie :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

- You cannot edit them by JavaScript i.e. by `document.cookie`.
- But you can edit by browser dev tools.

The purpose of `httpOnly` is not to defend against client because ultimately cookies are files stored on client so cannot enforce restrictions on client but it is to protect against client-side JavaScript which is simple terms `document.cookie`.